# Ruby async whois

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, eventmachine, whois

I'm using [whois](https://github.com/weppos/whois) to perform and parse whois queries. The problem is: i need to perform much more. Thousands and thousands. I found async package [em-whois](https://github.com/mikejarema/em-whois), which sounds perfect for me. This is simple addon for [whois](https://github.com/weppos/whois), which relies on **Ruby Fibers** and [em-synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony).

My current code to perform whois queries looks like this:

```
...
c = Whois::Client.new(:timeout => timeout)
r = c.query(domain)
...
```

After I've installed [em-whois](https://github.com/mikejarema/em-whois), i'm trying to extend [this basic example](https://github.com/mikejarema/em-whois/blob/master/examples/async_whois.rb).

My code looks like this now, and still is very slow:

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib'
require 'em-whois'
EM.synchrony do  
  domain = ARGV[0] || "github.com"
  $i = 0;
  $num = 100;
  arr = Array.new($num)
  # perform all queries
  begin
     puts("Inside the loop i = #$i" );
     $i += 1;
     arr[$i] = Whois.whois(domain);
  end while $i < $num
  $i = 0;
  # get all results
  begin
     $i += 1;
    puts "\r#{domain}\n#{"-" * domain.length}"
    [:available?, :status, :expires_on].each do |k|
      puts "#{k}: #{arr[$i].properties[k]}"
    end
  end while $i < $num
  EM.stop
end
```

**How do i perform batch queries (1k of domains) using async power of [whois](https://github.com/weppos/whois) and [em-whois](https://github.com/mikejarema/em-whois) ?**

I don't have any experience with ruby before. I'm Python/C/PHP developer. Please help.

Comment: Opening up multiple simultaneous connections to a whois server seems like a good way to get permanently blocked.

Comment: my question is more theoretical. i need help with code, i'm aware of limitation

Comment: But it's quite possible that the server is throttling you, and your code is fine.  If you profile the code, does it sit a lot in I/O wait?

Comment: You need help with more than the code. The concept is flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from author of the library. Example linked [here](https://github.com/mikejarema/em-whois/blob/master/examples/async_parallel_whois.rb).

```
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib'
require 'em-whois'
require 'atomic'

# Asynchronous, parallel multi-domain WHOIS lookup
domains = ARGV.empty? ? ["github.com", "google.com", "bing.com", "yahoo.com", "mikejarema.com"] : ARGV
whois   = {}

EM.synchrony do  

  # Progress indicator
  EM.add_periodic_timer(0.1) do
    STDERR.print "."
  end

  # Exit condition
  EM.add_periodic_timer(0.1) do
    if domains.size == whois.keys.size
      puts ""
      whois.each do |k,v|
        if v.properties[:available?]
          puts "#{k}: available"
        else
          puts "#{k}: taken, expires #{v.properties[:expires_on]}"
        end
      end

      EM.stop
    end
  end

  # Async WHOIS lookup - fire and forget via parallel fibers
  domains.each do |i|
    Fiber.new do
      whois[i] = Whois.whois(i)
    end.resume
  end

end
```

Comment: I'm the author of em-whois and provided the above code, and want to be clear I strongly frown on unauthorized WHOIS-data harvesting. That said, there are two caveats to the above solution: 1) it fires ALL whois queries at approx the same time, further work can be done to control the request frequency (eg. 100/s) 2) this script quickly hits WHOIS rate limits when run from a single IP, proxying across IPs is another consideration.

Comment: Third caveat: 3) in production use-cases, exceptions should be handled within the "fire and forget" fibers, otherwise the exit condition may never be satisfied.